# how do i solve it ' error Command failed with exit code 1.' RN

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 Task :app:processDevelopmentDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopmentDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:developmentDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:9.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
```

MY PROJECT / android/app/build.gradle is

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8,9)'

}
```

after =>

```
repositories {
  // You can also use jcenter if you prefer
  mavenCentral() 
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:9.+'
```

and gradlew clean , gradlew build

but I had the same problem.

I need your help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this problem .

2022-05-10 ,

RN version 0.64.2 => 0.65.2

so, this problem has been solved